# How can I make my menu automatically scale itself to fit different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, autoscaling

I've created my first sexy menu using CSS and HTML, but how can I make it automatically re-scale in size depending on the screen size. When viewing the webpage on and iPad the menu goes off the page?

http://ahdecor8.co.uk/menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify diffent CSS style options for different screen sizes, please check the url below to see how to do this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: This hasn't helped unfortunately, any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you show me the code you are using with the media size?

Comment: Can you add the @media objects to make it resize automatically, so I can see if you did that correctly?

Comment: Done, I've added the code to the top and closed it at the bottom. Do I have to add a certain thing for each element as well? New to this so thank you for your help dude! :)

Comment: You currently have everything in the media, you just need to make a seperate media part at the bottom of your page, where you only specify what has to be overwritten when the screen size is smaller than it usually should be. like this (at the bottom of your page, keeping the working code the same)

http://pastebin.com/4Yt0Dqer